# Django - How can you execute a process as a user other than the apache user

Tags: django, apache, configuration

I have a django web server which allows users to run jobs/tasks on our server. When a job is run from the web application, it is run as the www-data user. We would like the jobs to be run as the actual logged in user. To do this, we would obviously need to authenticate against the linux authentication system so that the users can log in with their server credentials and then we would need to somehow make all tasks run by that user run as their user on the server and not the www-data user. Is there a way to do this, possibly using ldap authentication?

We are using the Django web framework on Ubuntu 12.04. The web server is hosted with Apache2. The web server will be run on a local network and not be accessible from outside our building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my answer might not satisfy all of your needs and it's not very fast to implement, but I was thinking that in your Django app you could send a Linux `su - your_user` command (which would set the correct Linux user based on the currently logged in Django user) using Python's `subprocess` and then, still using `subprocess`, call the jobs/tasks which need to be executed.

Subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html

EDIT: you can also have a look at Pexpect https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late accept. I ended up doing this as suggested with Pexpect :-)